# Does a plane algebraic curve of degree d>1 with $\frac{1}{2}d(d-1)$ singularities exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In case it exists, it must be reducible, because the maximum number of singularities in an irreducible curve is $\frac{1}{2}(d-1)(d-2)<\frac{1}{2}d(d-1)$. Does it exist? Could we find an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: $\frac{1}{2}d(d-1) = {d \choose 2}$.

Hint 2: If we take $d$ general lines in the plane, in how many points do two of them meet?

Comment: Ok, two of them meet in one point, and there are $\frac{1}{2}d(d-1)$ ways to take 2 different lines, but, how do we know there are not repeated points?

Comment: Have you tried the case $d = 2$, say by drawing some lines on a piece of paper?  Then try $d = 3$ ... .

Comment: @Gauloises by choosing the lines to be general you exclude the case of repeated points

Comment: @Gauloises: as Irfan said, _general_ is the keyword here. Think about how you can pick the lines one after another, to avoid any three being concurrent.